# file dbf is not marked with a code page

Tags: php, dbf, visual-foxpro

I have created a dbf file using dbase_create() function in PHP. The file is successfully created but the problem is whenever I open the file in visual foxpro 9, it says

"File mydbffile.dbf is not marked with with a code page"

Then I need to select from the list of code pages.

Is there a way to set the code page automatically?

Comment: Sadly, I too am searching for a way from php to specify the codepage.  And have also noticed that php drops the structured complex index marker from the table header.  
I'm thinking PHP support is low for this especially since you can't create indexes from php.
Hopefully this technology dies off from usage but until then I'm stuck with these guys who use it still -_-, Anyone have an answer for this guy? And me?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify NOCPTRANS for character fields when creating the table.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (field1 C(10) NOCPTRANS, field2 C(10) NOCPTRANS, memo1 M NOCPTRANS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I do it in PHP using dbase_create()? I have searched it for answers and I came up with this: dbase_create("mytable",array("column1","C",30,0,true)) and I think that the "true" there is for the NOCPTRANS. Or am I wrong with that?

Comment: But the code that I said above doesn't work. How can I tell dbase_create() that my table will have NOCPTRANS?

Comment: Not being familiar with PHP connecting to a database, is there some connection string like it is typically done in .net?  If so, I THINK there is an option to tell the default codepage.

Answer (score 0):

NOCPTRANS doesn't related to DBF file code page. You should specify it explicitly, as in CREATE TABLE clause. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_Name CODEPAGE = 1251 (field1 C(10), field2 I(4))
```